# Strange wordpress behavior

Tags: wordpress

This is the first time I have seen this, and have no clue why its happening? The image is a shot of my console when just trying to go to a page on my website. Where does the .html come from?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I placed under website oodsideales.com > Apache & Nginx > Additional Ngix directives default nginx rewrite rules:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
set $test P;
}
if ($uri !~ ^/(plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon|internal-nginx-static-location)) {
set $test "${test}C";
}
if ($test = PC) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}
```